# Oracle combining two monthly sums from to different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, multiple-tables

I'm stuck on this for ages. It's probably something obvious, but I don't have that much SQL knowledge to be honest. I got the following two tables:

```
Date1       Cost1
-------------------
01-01-14    50,65
02-01-14    12,12
```

and

```
Date2       Cost2
-------------------
01-01-14    123,12
02-01-14    14,15
```

I need to following output:

```
Number of month    Total amount of table 1 and 2 for that specific month
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                  2425252,52
2                  53252,89
```

I got the queries working for the single tables and I could sort them within my actual code but I just know it is possible with a query but I simply can't find out how. I've been looking at inner and outer joins, but since I use two group by statements I get a result for each month number times 12 and with incorrect values.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How does `50,65` and `123,12` for January become `2425252,52`?

Comment: Sorry, these are just random testnumbers. Every month has around 600 values which leads to quite high totals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can union the results together, and then sum those results. Keep in mind that you are crossing years based on the OP.  If this is not the intent, then I also provided an alternative grouped by year and month.

Grouped by month:

```
SELECT c1.monthNum
    , sum(c1.cost) as cost
FROM 
(
    SELECT to_char(t1.date1, 'MM') as monthNum, SUM(t1.cost1)  as cost
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE ..your table1 where clause here...
    GROUP BY to_char(t1.date1, 'MM') 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT to_char(t2.date1, 'MM') as monthNum, SUM(t2.cost1)  as cost
    FROM table1 t2
    WHERE ..your table2 where clause here...    
    GROUP BY to_char(t2.date1, 'MM')
) c1
GROUP BY c1.monthNum
```

OR Grouped by year:

```
SELECT c1.yearNum
    , c1.monthNum
    , sum(c1.cost) as cost
FROM 
(
    SELECT to_char(t1.date1, 'YYYY') AS yearNum, to_char(t1.date1, 'MM') as monthNum, SUM(t1.cost1)  as cost
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE ..your table1 where clause here...
    GROUP BY to_char(t1.date1, 'YYYY'), to_char(t1.date1, 'MM') 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT to_char(t2.date1, 'YYYY') AS yearNum, to_char(t2.date1, 'MM') as monthNum, SUM(t2.cost1)  as cost
    FROM table1 t2
    WHERE ..your table2 where clause here...    
    GROUP BY to_char(t2.date1, 'YYYY'), to_char(t2.date1, 'MM')
) c1
GROUP BY c1.yearNum, c1.monthNum
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used to group by days.
I have data inserted with date `29-APR-15 and 30-APR-15`

```
select 
     extract(month from tbl_inc.date_id) as mon,
     extract(year from tbl_inc.date_id) as yr ,
     ta as incamt ,
     da as expamt ,
     tbl_inc.*,
     tbl_expn.*
from 
    (select trunc(date_id) date_id, user_id, sum(amount) ta 
from 
    tbl_inc 
group by 
    trunc(date_id), user_id ) tbl_inc,
    ( select trunc(date_id) date_id, user_id, sum(amount) da 
from 
    tbl_expn 
group by 
    trunc(date_id), user_id ) tbl_expn 
where 
     tbl_inc.user_id = tbl_expn.user_id 
and  
     tbl_inc.date_id = tbl_expn.date_id 
and  
     tbl_inc.user_id='222' 
and  
     extract(year from tbl_inc.date_id)='2015' 
order by 
     extract(month from tbl_inc.date_id)
```

The result of this query is as follows

```
MON YR      INCAMT  EXPAMT  DATE_ID    USER_ID  TA      DATE_ID     USER_ID DA
4   2015    9155    2600    30-APR-15   222     9155    30-APR-15   222     2600
4   2015    45      435     29-APR-15   222     45      29-APR-15   222     435
```

Somebody here help me to get the following output from the query

```
MON YR      INCAMT  EXPAMT  USER_ID
4   2015    9200    3035    222
```